# Error al crear registro MYSQL , PHP , HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hola soy nuevo en la programacion,
comencé a aprender PHP relativamente recientemente y en el proceso estoy tratando de insertar los datos de un formulario en una base de datos usando PHP, ya que he estado buscando una forma segura a través de declaraciones y objetos preparados y estoy tratando de hacerlo aunque No sé si es la forma correcta.

Solo me da la leyenda de Error al registrarse

**Archivo registrar.php**

```php
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
//Recibir los datos y almacenarlos en variables
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$seudonimo = $_POST["seudonimo"];
$tipo = $_POST["tipo"];
$pais = $_POST["pais"];
$enlace = $_POST["enlace"];
$echos = $_POST["echos"];
//Consulta para insertar
$insertar = "INSERT INTO `tbl_listanegra`(seudonimo,nombre,tipo,pais,enlace,echos) VALUES ('$seudonimo','$nombre','$tipo','$pais','$enlace','$echos')";
//Ejecutar consulta
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);
if (!$resultado) {
    echo 'Error al registrarse';
}else{
    echo 'Usuario registrado exitosamente';
}
//Cerrrar conexion
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

**Archivo conexion.php**

```php
<?php
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "xxxx","ml");
if (!$conexion){
    echo 'Error al conectar en la base de datos';
}
else{
    echo 'Conectado exitosamente';
}
```

**Archivo Index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Formulario de Registro</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Formulario de Registro</h1>
<form action="php/registrar.php" method="post" class="form-register">
    <h2 class="form-titulo">CREA UNA CUENTA</h2>
    <div class="contenedor-inputs">
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="nombre" class="input-48" required>
        <input type="text" id="seudonimo" name="seudonimo" placeholder="seudonimo" class="input-48" required>
        <input type="text" id="tipo" name="tipo" placeholder="tipo" class="input-100" required>
        <input type="text" id="pais" name="pais" placeholder="pais" class="input-48" required>
        <input type="text" id="enlace" name="enlace" placeholder="enlace" class="input-48"required >
        <input type="text" id="echos" name="echos" placeholder="echos" class="input-100" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Registrar" class="btn-enviar">
        <p class="form-link">Ya tienes una cuenta?<a href="#">Ingresa aquí</a></p>
    </div>
</form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Y la estructura de la **Base de datos**

[image: Estructura de base de datos]

No encuentro cual es el error ,

Comment: La forma en la que mides si existe o no error, no es la mejor (*al menos no para depurar*), revisa [la doc. de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php#refsect1-mysqli.error-examples) en el apartado de ejemplos el uso del método `mysqli_error` y aplicalo en tu consulta para saber realmente que pasa

Answer (score 1):

Mi solucion fue agregar

```php
or die("Error : " . mysqli_error($conexion));
```

Para detectar el error me di cuenta que en mi base de datos no estaba aceptando valores nulos ,marque los nulos y ahora funciona sin problema.

```php
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
//Recibir los datos y almacenarlos en variables
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$seudonimo = $_POST["seudonimo"];
$tipo = $_POST["tipo"];
$pais = $_POST["pais"];
$enlace = $_POST["enlace"];
$echos = $_POST["echos"];
$ciudad = $_POST["ciudad"];
$provincia_estado = $_POST["provincia_estado"];
$reporte = $_POST["reporte"];
$tipo_cuenta = $_POST["tipo_cuenta"];
//Consulta para insertar
$insertar = "INSERT INTO tbl_listanegra(seudonimo, nombre, tipo, pais, enlace, echos, ciudad, provincia_estado, reporte, tipo_cuenta) VALUES ('$seudonimo','$nombre','$tipo','$pais','$enlace', '$echos', '$ciudad', '$provincia_estado', '$reporte', '$tipo_cuenta')";
//Ejecutar consulta
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar)or die("Error : " . mysqli_error($conexion));
if (!$resultado) {
    echo 'Error al registrarse';
}else{
    echo 'Usuario registrado exitosamente';
}
//Cerrrar conexion
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que no has verificado si se ha pulsado el botón  tipo Submit.
Esto puedes verificarlo con: `if(isset($_POST["btn-enviar"]))`

Puedes probar el siguiente código:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

//Recibir los datos y almacenarlos en variables
if (isset($_POST["btn-enviar"])) {
 $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
 $seudonimo = $_POST["seudonimo"];
 $tipo = $_POST["tipo"];
 $pais = $_POST["pais"];
 $enlace = $_POST["enlace"];
 $echos = $_POST["echos"];
 //Consulta para insertar
 $insertar = "INSERT INTO 
 `tbl_listanegra`(seudonimo,nombre,tipo,pais,enlace,echos) VALUES 
 ('$seudonimo','$nombre','$tipo','$pais','$enlace','$echos')";
 //Ejecutar consulta
 $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);
 if (!$resultado) {
    echo 'Error al registrarse';
 } else{
    echo 'Usuario registrado exitosamente';
 }
 //Cerrrar conexion
 mysqli_close($conexion);
}
```

Actualización (20/12/20, 07:43 AM, GMT-3):
También puede ser que en la consulta, estés usando este tipo de simbolo: "`"

Puedes probar el siguiente código también:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

//Recibir los datos y almacenarlos en variables
if (isset($_POST["btn-enviar"])) {
 $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
 $seudonimo = $_POST["seudonimo"];
 $tipo = $_POST["tipo"];
 $pais = $_POST["pais"];
 $enlace = $_POST["enlace"];
 $echos = $_POST["echos"];
 //Consulta para insertar
 $insertar = "INSERT INTO 
 tbl_listanegra(seudonimo,nombre,tipo,pais,enlace,echos) VALUES 
 ('$seudonimo','$nombre','$tipo','$pais','$enlace','$echos')";
 //Ejecutar consulta
 $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $insertar);
 if (!$resultado) {
    echo 'Error al registrarse';
 } else{
    echo 'Usuario registrado exitosamente';
 }
 //Cerrrar conexion
 mysqli_close($conexion);
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta hermano,  agregue el mysqli_error y el problema era la base de datos , no le estaba permitiendo agregar valores nulos

Comment: @JonathanCamacho, en estos casos considera publicar como respuesta tu solución y marcarla como aceptada por favor

Comment: @pabdani, si te refieres a las backticks aquí `INSERT INTO tbl_listanegra` te comento que son válidas y hasta necesarias cuando se usan palabras reservadas de mysql en el nombre de la tabla y/o columnas